# Generate spool in based on condition in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-scripts

I need to write an oracle sql script based on some condition.

Like User has to type 'y' or 'n' if he types 'y' then i need to

```
accept gen prompt 'Enter y if you want to generate spool' default 'n'
spool c:\a.spl

    SELECT CUST_ID INTO NO 
       FROM ACC_MASTER 
       WHERE ACCOUNT_NO='&CRN' 
          AND BRANCH_NO='&BRN';


    select * from a where lid=no;
    select * from b where lid=no;
    select * from c where lid=no;

spool off;
```

If the user types 'N' Nothing needs to be selected.

Please advise

Comment: Have you tried writing a procedure with one parameter accepting your character `Y`?

Comment: No,Sir. Could you please advise how to do that

Comment: Try downloading Oracle SQLDeveloper. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnpt than using sql plus command.

Comment: I cant use plsql because if use plsql I ave put the columns in select * from a into some vaiables.

Comment: do you want the spool to be conditional or do you want the query results to be conditional based on the prompt answer?

Comment: I want the spool file to be conditional

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use a bash statement ("if-fi") if you use Linux, or statement "if" for Windows to work around it.

Comment: Could you please tell me how do you use if statement in SQL script.Because if i have write like this
if (gen=='y') then
  do all the ops;
end if; 
will not work beacuse selct col  into i have to use

Comment: for example for linux for bash you would write `#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter y if you want to generate spool, followed by [ENTER]:"

read choice

if [ "$choice" == "y" ]; then
  sqlplus /
  spool c:\a.spl
  ...
  spool off;
fi`

Comment: I m running through sql developer in windows not unix/linux

Comment: Describe your scenario, I can't understand why you need this. I use the clause "spool" to make sure that my script has been run successfully on other servers by someone (not me).

Answer (score 0):

Create a noop file first

```
C:\>echo. > null.sql
```

script

```
set ver off

accept gen prompt 'Enter y if you want to generate spool ' default 'n'

set term off
column col noprint new_value scriptname
select decode(lower('&gen'),'y','myspoolscript','n', 'null') col from dual;
set term on

set ver on

@&scriptname
```